# 'Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database' in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I want to create a database in the installation process using WiX 3.6. I followed many tutorials, but I think there is something I am doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">

    <Product Id="{A704CA9E-2833-4276-A8A8-148F1047332F}" Name="DbInstallerTest" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="2de42bd8-acc2-48bf-b3c6-09745d3a2ea4">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="DbInstallerTest" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="DbInstallerTest" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

            <Component Id="CMPDbInsatller"
                       Guid="{1749E57D-9CE4-42F8-924C-2A2E368B51E4}">
                <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
                <util:User Id="SqlUser"
                           Name="sa"
                           Password="Abc123@"/>
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp2"
                       Guid="{C3596364-61A0-4628-9153-1BA11DB4B778}">
                <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
                <sql:SqlDatabase Id="Id_db"
                                 Database="TestDatabase1"
                                 Server="(local)\SQLExpress"
                                 CreateOnInstall="yes"
                                 User="SqlUser"
                                 DropOnUninstall="yes">
                </sql:SqlDatabase>
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The above code gives the following error.

> Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database: TestDatabase1. error detail: Unknown error.

Here is the log content,

```
=== Logging started: 2/18/2013  11:00:59 ===
Action 11:00:59: INSTALL.
Action start 11:00:59: INSTALL.
Action 11:00:59: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 11:00:59: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 11:00:59: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 11:00:59: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 11:00:59: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 11:00:59: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 11:00:59: ValidateProductID.
Action start 11:00:59: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 11:00:59: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 11:00:59: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:00:59: CostInitialize.
Action ended 11:00:59: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 11:00:59: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:00:59: FileCost.
Action ended 11:00:59: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 11:00:59: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:00:59: CostFinalize.
Action ended 11:00:59: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 11:00:59: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 11:00:59: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 11:00:59: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action 11:00:59: ExecuteAction.
Action start 11:00:59: ExecuteAction.
Action start 11:01:01: INSTALL.
Action start 11:01:01: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 11:01:01: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 11:01:01: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 11:01:01: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 11:01:01: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: CostInitialize.
Action ended 11:01:01: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: FileCost.
Action ended 11:01:01: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: CostFinalize.
Action ended 11:01:01: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 11:01:01: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action start 11:01:01: InstallValidate.
Action ended 11:01:01: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 11:01:01: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 11:01:01: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 11:01:01: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 11:01:01: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:01: UninstallSqlData.
Action ended 11:01:02: UninstallSqlData. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:02: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 11:01:02: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
Action start 11:01:02: RemoveFolders.
Action ended 11:01:02: RemoveFolders. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:02: CreateFolders.
Action ended 11:01:02: CreateFolders. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:02: ConfigureUsers.
Action start 11:01:02: CreateUserRollback.
Action ended 11:01:02: CreateUserRollback. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:02: CreateUser.
Action ended 11:01:02: CreateUser. Return value 1.
Action ended 11:01:02: ConfigureUsers. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:02: InstallFiles.
Action ended 11:01:02: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:02: InstallSqlData.
Action start 11:01:19: CreateDatabase.
Action ended 11:01:19: CreateDatabase. Return value 1.
Action ended 11:01:19: InstallSqlData. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:19: RegisterUser.
Action ended 11:01:19: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:19: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 11:01:19: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:19: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 11:01:19: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:19: PublishProduct.
Action ended 11:01:19: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 11:01:19: InstallFinalize.
CreateDatabase:  Error 0x80004005: failed to create to database: 'TestDatabase1', error:

unknown error
Error 26201. Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database: TestDatabase1, error detail:

unknown error.
MSI (s) (94!44) [11:01:47:973]: Product: DbInstallerTest -- Error 26201. Error -2147467259:

failed to create SQL database: TestDatabase1, error detail: unknown error.

CustomAction CreateDatabase returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100%

accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 11:01:47: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:01:48: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:01:48: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:01:48: INSTALL. Return value 3.
=== Logging stopped: 2/18/2013  11:01:48 ===
MSI (c) (C0:94) [11:01:48:208]: Product: DbInstallerTest -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (C0:94) [11:01:48:209]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name:

DbInstallerTest. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft.

Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10):

We chased this error around for a week before *finally* resolving it by going into the SQL Server Configuration Manager → SQL Server Network Configuration → Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (for us, the default instance) → Enabling Named Pipes and TCP/IP protocols.

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing this exact issue, and I browsed a lot of forums to get that solved. This was the only thing which worked for me. On my computer, SQL Server Express Edition database creation failed with
-2147467259: failed to create SQL database:

> After days of hacking I finally found the solution! All you need to do
>   is use .\sqlexpress instead of localhost\sqlexpress or
>   127.0.0.1\sqlexpress in your connection string. I think (and I might be terribly wrong here) when you use .\sqlexpress in connection string
>   installer uses Shared Memory instead of Named Pipes or TCP/IP.

Source: *[Solution to -2147467259: failed to create SQL database](http://geekrick.blogspot.in/2008/07/solution-to-2147467259-failed-to-create.html)*

Comment: Enabling Named Pipes is only way it worked for me as well.
Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

Err 26201 is more useful. You should also see more information in the event logs.

Your code indicates that you are using mixed mode on the SQL instance and authenticating as a SQL login.  This indicates that the problem is likely that your SQL service account doesn't have permissions to create the MDF and LDF files in the default locations.

See this thread for more info:

[Error 26201. Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Error-26201-Error-2147467259-failed-to-create-SQL-database-td6163225.html)

Answer (score 2):

So I am also getting an error in my WiX installer logs also, however slightly different.

Environment:

- WebServer = Windows 2008 R2
- SQLServer = Windows 2008 32-bit with SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard
- Mixed Mode Authentication
- Default SQL Instance

Error:

> ExecuteSqlStrings:  Entering ExecuteSqlStrings in
> C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1EC7.tmp, version 3.6.3303.0
>
> ExecuteSqlStrings:  Error 0x80004005: failed to connect to database:
> 'DatabaseNameBla'
>
> Error 26203. Failed to connect to SQL database.
> (-2147467259   DatabaseNameBla      ) MSI (s) (20!30) [10:16:32:225]:
> Product: Bla Services -- Error 26203. Failed to connect to SQL
> database.  (-2147467259   DatabaseNameBla      )

Research:

- Instance DB seems to have only 1.6 GB left on the hard drive. << this might be bad...
- My user is sysadmin
- Access Through SQL Management Tools has no problems with the same user.
- SLQ Logs have nothing in them to assist with the error. Just noise.

My Solution:

- VM has a D drive with 50 GB free
- New Database Instance on D Drive
- New Instance Set to Mixed Mode
- Reinstalled. Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Summary:

So after hours of trying to figure out what the deal was. In the instance of this error, it was related to the hard drive free space size. Since the SQL Server was in production we were unable to expand the C drive to see if that fixed the default instance.